# Seed error ActiveModel::UnknownAttributeError: unknown attribute 'excerpt' for List

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I'm setting up my seed file to add some data to my Rails 5 app.
When I'm running `rake db:seed` I'm getting this error

```
rake aborted!
ActiveModel::UnknownAttributeError: unknown attribute 'excerpt' for List.
```

Cannot really understand why I'm getting this. I'm using PostgreSQL as DB and Rails 5.2. I'm trying to build an API.

I set up the DB did the migrations but seed doesn't work.

I have also another 2 models and a controller for items.

Seed file:

```
List.create(title:"West Sweden Road Trip", excerpt:"A cool road trip with stops in harbors of the coast")
```

My model is:

```
class List < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :list_items
  has_many :items, through: :list_items
end
```

Controller:

```
module Api::V1
  class ListsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :set_list, only: [:show, :update, :destroy]

    # GET /lists
    def index
      @lists = List.order(:id)

      render json: @lists
    end

    # GET /lists/1
    def show
      render json: @list
    end

    # POST /lists
    def create
      @list = List.new(list_params)

      if @list.save
        render json: @list, status: :created
      else
        render json: @list.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
      end
    end

    # PATCH/PUT /lists/1
    def update
      if @list.update(list_params)
        render json: @list
      else
        render json: @list.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
      end
    end

    # DELETE /lists/1
    def destroy
      @list.destroy
      if @list.destroy
        head :no_content, status: :ok
      else
        render json: @list.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
      end
    end

    private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_list
      @list = List.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Only allow a trusted parameter "white list" through.
    def list_params
      params.require(:list).permit(:title, :excerpt, :description, :upvotes)
    end
  end
end
```

My Schema:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 2018_10_14_135801) do

  # These are extensions that must be enabled in order to support this database
  enable_extension "plpgsql"

  create_table "items", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "type"
    t.string "name"
    t.text "excerpt"
    t.text "description"
    t.string "url"
    t.integer "upvotes"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "list_items", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.bigint "list_id"
    t.bigint "item_id"
    t.text "description"
    t.integer "position"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["item_id"], name: "index_list_items_on_item_id"
    t.index ["list_id"], name: "index_list_items_on_list_id"
  end

  create_table "lists", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "title"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  add_foreign_key "list_items", "items"
  add_foreign_key "list_items", "lists"
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> rake aborted! ActiveModel::UnknownAttributeError: unknown attribute
>   'excerpt' for List.

Well, the `List` **doesn't have** an attribute called `excerpt`, but the `Item` has `excerpt` attribute

Change it to

```
List.create(title:"West Sweden Road Trip")
```

**Update:**

If you want to add `excerpt` column to `List`, then generate a migration with

```
rails g migration add_excerpt_to_lists excerpt:text
```

and then do `rake db:migrate`

Comment: That was right but I was doing along this tutorial https://medium.com/@bruno_boehm/reactjs-ruby-on-rails-api-heroku-app-2645c93f0814 maybe that is wrong then or I missed something?

Comment: @Jakub The tutorial is right! In the tutorial, the author has created `List` model with `excerpt` column. See this `rails g scaffold List title:string excerpt:text description:text upvotes:integer`

Comment: Ah ok so I missed that. Can I add excerpt manually somehow to avoid this error?
@Pavan

Comment: @Jakub you need to generate a migration for that. Check my update